# Postgres 9 super slow simple delete

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-administration

I have a substantial database... not a very large one - around 1gb of data in total.

I need to delete some rows from several tables. For example I have a table

```
 Order
 id     | ... | status   | ...
 1      | ... | 1        | ...
 ...
 40     | ... | 20       | ...
 41     | ... | 1        | ...
 ...
 470000 | ... | 12       | ...
```

Now I want to delete all orders that have `status=1`

I presume I do it with:

> DELETE FROM Order WHERE status=1

All nice and simple it would seem but it takes ages! When I have run this query it was still running at 100% CPU usage after 40 min... when I killed the process nothing was deleted.

When I tried limiting the scope by using

> DELETE FROM Order WHERE status=1 AND id<1000

it took couple of minutes to delete some 200 rows....

Is there anything I am missing in my configuration? Anything I should look for/check/change? Any ideas at all why its so bloody inefficient?

Let me add that I am usually working with MySQL and need to manage this postgres database but don't really have any experience with postgres, so it may be something very simple.

Indexes are on both id and status columns.

Table has some 500k rows, around half needs to be deleted.

Execution plan:

```
Delete  (cost=0.00..19474.19 rows=266518 width=6)
->  Seq Scan on Orders  (cost=0.00..19474.19 rows=266518 width=6)
Filter: (statusid = 1)
```

There are no triggers or rules of any sort. What's more, I didn't add this is a fresh copy of the table, I mean it was moved from other server with export/import. Perhaps this plays a role somehow?

Will deleting indexes help?

Comment: Do you have an index on the `status` column? How does the execution plan for the delete statement look like?

Comment: By running the "EXPLAIN" command: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html

Comment: How many rows does the table have? And how may of those have status=1? Anyhow deleting 266518 rows shouldn't take 40min...

Comment: Then it makes sense that the index is not used. But still the deletion shouldn't take that long. I have no idea how to find out what is slowing you down thoug. You'll probably get better help by posting this to the PG mailing list.

Comment: 1) Are there any triggers (or rules) defined on the table? 2) You could delete all indexes and recreate them afterwards (You do not need an index for the delete, deleting half of the table will result in sequential table scan anyway.

Comment: It would be good if you posted the table definition and also if there are other tables with any `FOREIGN KEY` that references this table and has `ON DELETE` action defined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Having nothing deleted after you killed the process is EXACTLY what you should see.

The delete happens as a transaction, meaning that either everything is deleted, or nothing is.  To make sure that this can happen, the rows need to be copied somewhere before deleting them.  Which means that deleting 250k rows takes about as much time as inserting that many rows.  In some cases it can be faster to create a new table with everything NOT deleted and rename the new table to the old one.

If this is being moved from another db, you will probably be better off if you can keep the 250k rows from being inserted in the first place.

(This is general RDBMS wisdom, not postgresql specific - the details of how postgres MVCC works may differ significantly.)

Comment: Hi, This is exactly as I have begun to suspect ... can I switch of transaction for the duration of deleting? After all I don't care much if it deletes only 100k before something happens cause I can always run delete again.

Comment: How about using some kind of incremental approach (pseudocode): for (my_id = 0; my_id < max(id); my_id += 1000) { delete from order where status = 1 and id between my_id and my_id + 1000; commit }

Answer (score 3):

It is much quicker use COPY FROM / TURNCATE /COPY TO on big tables.

But, of course, you have to be careful with references and if possible, disable triggers.